# Python permision denied to open a directory on Windows

Tags: python

I want to read all bytes from a disk `E:` or my SD-card, and my code is:

```
with open("E:", "rb") as byteData:
    try:
       byteData.seek(self.offset.value() * 512, os.SEEK_SET)
       print(self.offset.value() * 512)
       block = byteData.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
    except ValueError: # Empty offsetSpinbox
       return
```

and I get this error error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    with open("E:", "rb") as byteData:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:'
```

Comment: I'm not sure Windows will allow any program, no matter the language or privileges, to open a raw drive to read all bytes simply by specifying the drive as the filename.

Comment: ok, but any solution for read a byte from a directory maybe? thanks

Comment: You can't open a directory with `open`. Does iterating over all files in the directory and reading their bytes satisfy your need?

Comment: Thank you, but on my case, i must read without file, cause the byte write on sector

Answer (score 0):

You could try running as admin from `cmd.exe` or even create a shortcut to execute your script with all privileges

Comment: yeah, i try running as admin too

Answer (score 0):

To access raw bytes from the drive `E:`, you can consider using `\\.\E:`. Please note that reading raw bytes requires you to be aligned.

```
# The backslashes need to be escaped.
with open("\\\\.\\E:", "rb") as byteData:
    try:
       byteData.seek(self.offset.value() * 512, os.SEEK_SET)
       print(self.offset.value() * 512)
       block = byteData.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
    except ValueError: # Empty offsetSpinbox
       return
```

You can also read directly from physical disks with `\\.\physicaldrive0` where 0 can be the index of your disk.

Sidenote: The above operations requires administrator privileges.